# React-router changes location but doesn't render component

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-v4

I'm using react-router **v4** for routing in React. The issues i'm facing is that the react-router changes the location but is unable to render the component. I heard that using redux with react **blocks updates** but i'm not using **redux** here .

**Sidebar.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router, 
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class Sidebar extends Component {
        render () {
            return (
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pill">
                            <span><i className="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i> menu</span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="pill">

                            <ul className="nav nav-pills flex-column sidebar">
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
                                        <i className="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard 
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#students" className="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse">
                                        <i className="fa fa-users"></i> Students 
                                    </a>
                                    <ul className="collapse" id="students" style={{marginLeft: '-25px'}}>
                                        <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/students" className="nav-link"><i className="fa fa-eye"></i> View students</Link></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </Router>
            )
        }

    }

export default withRouter(Sidebar);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Students from './Students';


class App extends Component {   

    render() {     

        const { match } = this.props;
        return (
            <Router>
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container-fluid main">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-2 area-left">
                        <Sidebar />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-10 area-right float-right">
                        <div>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                            <Route exact path="/students" component={Students} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

When route is **/**

[image]

When route is **/students**

[image]

Reloading the page renders the component

Comment: Why do you have two routers in your application? Router is HOC provider, you only need one per your application. It wraps your entire project.

Comment: @mattdevio Can you give me the solution in answer to let me understand well?

Comment: Try importing just straight up 'Router' from react-router-dom instead of BrowserRouter. Also, you do not need a router in your side bar. You only need to wrap your top level component with the router & use Link inside of your components to redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Link` you specified in your sidebar is trying to use the Router you wrapped the component in, not the Router you defined your links in.

This is what your sidebar component should look like.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Link,
    withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

class Sidebar extends Component {
        render () {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pill">
                            <span><i className="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i> menu</span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="pill">

                            <ul className="nav nav-pills flex-column sidebar">
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
                                        <i className="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard 
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#students" className="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse">
                                        <i className="fa fa-users"></i> Students 
                                    </a>
                                    <ul className="collapse" id="students" style={{marginLeft: '-25px'}}>
                                        <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/students" className="nav-link"><i className="fa fa-eye"></i> View students</Link></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            )
        }

    }

export default withRouter(Sidebar);
```

More explanation:
You should only wrap your top level component in the router since it for lack of better terms `spawns all the children` in your app. Furthermore, it will automatically inject the props for the router unless you are using redux. So unless you're using redux no need for withRouter() *.

*lmk if i'm wrong, i'm not an expert.

Example of your top level app component:

```
render() {
    return(
        <Router history={History}>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/student" component={Student} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Comment: Removing the Router from Sidebar.js solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially wrap your Route with Switch.

Update **App.js** to the below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Students from './Students';


class App extends Component {   

    render() {     

        const { match } = this.props;
        return (
            <Router>
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container-fluid main">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-2 area-left">
                        <Sidebar />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-10 area-right float-right">
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                            <Route exact path="/students" component={Students} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer didn't help.

Comment: ik im 4 years late but this comment is wild lol ^